# From within archive file, alter all XML files to remove nodes containing specific @Name value

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an archive file (similar to .zip or .7z file) containing a number of XML files, using the general structure:

```xml
<DataRequest>
  <DataObject>
    <DataProperty Name= "prop1">
      <SimpleProperty Value="abc"
    </DataProperty>
    <DataProperty Name= "propB">
      <SimpleProperty Value="123"
    </DataProperty>
    <DataProperty Name= "propX">
      <SimpleProperty Value="xyz"
    </DataProperty>
  </DataObject>
</DataRequest>
```

I would like to bulk alter these files to remove all `<DataProperty>` nodes have the `@Name` parameter = "prop1".

**EDIT**
As per @AnsgarWiechers answer below, I have updated my working code

```bsh
$zipFileName = "C:\Users\me\filename.bxp"
Add-Type -Assembly  System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
$zip = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::Open($zipfileName, "Update")
$editFile = $zip.Entries.Where({$_.Name -Like "*.xml"})
$xml = New-Object Xml

$editFile | ForEach-Object {
    $xml.Load($_.FullName)
    $xml.SelectNodes('//DataProperty[@Name="prop1"]') |
        ForEach-Object { $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }
    $xml.Save('C:\path\to\output.xml')
}
```

The issue here is how the file gets saved. I don't want to output a new .xml file. Rather, I would like to alter the .xml file as it stands within the .bxp archive.

Currently that process is manual. In the file explorer window, I can right click on the .bxp file and choose "7zip -> Open Archive", which opens a Notepad editor. Any changes that are saved from within that editor will affect the file that sits inside the .bxp. I am looking to replicate that process programatically.

If this is not possible, I can output the .xml file and add it to the archive manually. In that case, my issue would be altering the output file name for each .xml file in the loop. Can I set up a variable that will inherit the filename, and output that same file name? Is that what the `$_.FullName` variable does?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what `$_.FullName` does. How else did you think `xml.Load()` would open the different files from `$editFile`?

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is invalid. A [pipe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-3.0) connects the output of one statement/command to the input of another statement/command. You can wrap a long line *after* a pipe symbol, because PowerShell will then recognize that the statement is continued on the next line. But if you wrap a line *before* a pipe symbol PowerShell will not be able to auto-detect the line continuation and interpret both lines separately, because the first line contains a complete, valid statement, thus leading to the syntax error you observed.

If you want to wrap a line before a pipe you *must* escape the newline at the end of the first line with a backtick (`` ` ``).

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//DataProperty') `
    | ForEach-Object { $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }
```

But again, it's better style to wrap the line *after* the pipe symbol:

```
$xml.SelectNodes('//DataProperty') |
    ForEach-Object { $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }
```

Also, there is no reason for putting a pipe between `$xml = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)` and `$xml.SelectNodes('//DataProperty')`. The first statement assigns the parsed XML data structure to a variable that is then used in the second statement. The second statement does not read pipeline input. Technically you could feed the parsed XML data into a pipeline, but that would require another `ForEach-Object` around the `SelectNodes()`.

An argument could also be made that

```
$xml = New-Object Xml
$xml.Load($_.FullName)
```

is a cleaner way of loading the XML data than

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $_.FullName)
```

but in most scenarios both approaches will work.

With all the syntax issues out of the way, a filter in the [XPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ms256086(v=vs.100)) language is an expression in square brackets. In your case you want to remove nodes that have an attribute `Name` with the value `prop1`, so the filter would look like this: `[@Name="prop1"]`.

Change your code to something like this:

```
$xml = New-Object Xml
$editFile | ForEach-Object {
    $xml.Load($_.FullName)
    $xml.SelectNodes('//DataProperty[@Name="prop1"]') |
        ForEach-Object { $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_) }
}
```

and it should do what you expect.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that out and mark the answer if it works

Comment: @Samcd Note that so far your loop doesn't do anything with the modified XML. If you want to persist the change you need to save it back to a file.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: @Samcd `$xml.Save('C:\path\to\output.xml')` of course.

Comment: Is there any way to save the .xml file within the .bxp archive (i.e. the one the loop is "currently" editing), as opposed to outputting it to a new file? Also, I am assuming that `$xml.Save` should be within the `$editFile | ForEach-Object` loop, so if I am going to output a new file, I want to give each one a different name. I guess I can set up a variable to inherit the name of the .xml file currently being worked on, and use that as the output file name? Do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @Samcd How do you open the XML file? Have you tried saving it the same way? Please do not ask me to spoon-feed you a solution. That is not going to happen.

Comment: Thats not what I am looking for. For example, my current process for editing these files is manual: Right click on the .bxp file and choose "7zip -> Open Archive", which opens a Notepad editor. Any changes that are saved from within that editor will affect the file that sits inside the .bxp. I am looking to replicate that process.

Comment: @Samcd That is not what the code in your question says.